# How to convert Excel file being pass as XML from server to JavaScript(React)

Tags: reactjs, xml, asp.net-web-api

The API from the server(using ASP.NET web API) is passing an XML that contains data and my goal is to make the XML response from API downloadable as an Excel file from the browser after request call in the API. I'm using React for the front-end side.

This is my code when making the API call

```
export const downloadReports = (payload) => async (dispatch) => {
    await requestHelper(dispatch, RequestsEnum.downloadReports, async (_) => {
            const res = await defaultAxios.post(
                '/api/generateRecords',
                convertToJWT(payload)
            )
       
        console.log(res.data)

        dispatch({
            type: DEPOSIT_DOWNLOAD_DEPOSIT_REPORTS,
        })
    })
}
```

This is the XML format in the res.data I received after the API call is made

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"><ss:Styles><ss:Style ss:ID="1"><ss:Font ss:Bold="1"/></ss:Style></ss:Styles><ss:Worksheet ss:Name="REPORTS"><ss:Table><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Column ss:Width="200"/><ss:Row ss:StyleID="1"></ss:Row><ss:Row ss:StyleID="1"><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Application Number</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Customer Type</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Business Name</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Application Date</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Product Name</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Application Status</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Online Banking Status</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Updated By</ss:Data></ss:Cell></ss:Row><ss:Row><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">RB-03092021-252F1-BC</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">NEW</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">PostMan</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">09/03/2021</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Business Checking Account</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Disapproved</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">For Client Submission</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">For Client Submission</ss:Data></ss:Cell></ss:Row><ss:Row><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">RB-07092021-4E033-BC</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">NEW</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Test 0907</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">08/29/2021</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Business Checking Account</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">For Bank Review</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">For Client Submission</ss:Data></ss:Cell><ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">For Client Submission</ss:Data></ss:Cell></ss:Row></ss:Table></ss:Worksheet></ss:Workbook>
```

Any ideas, suggestions, or other ways to convert this to excel file and make it a downloadable file? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue recently, I tried below snippet. It worked for me.

```
const res = await axios.get("url-here", {
  { responseType: "arraybuffer", headers: { "Content-Type": "blob" } }
});

const fileURL = url.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = fileURL;
link.setAttribute("download", "filename.xls");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Thank you.